# How to keep track of interesting clips while recording

Tags: recording

I try to record some of my games, such as Diablo III, DayZ and Planetside 2, where the gameplay can be pretty intense at times. I often end up having 3-4hr sessions and equal length videos. Lots of standard, uninteresting gameplay, and few intense highlights.

I'd love to create 10-15 minute clips of the highlights of these sessions, especially in multiplayer where I play with friends. I almost always loose track of that one special kill, a killing streak, or any other bits of interesting gameplay. Is there a way to keep track of these things as they happen, without having to re-watch the entire video?

I am using DXtory and FFsplit as capturing / recording software.

Could be a tip or technique, mobile app, keyboard macro or annotator, anything that allows me to easily find interesting bits of footage in those marathon recording sessions. Thanks!

Comment: Does your phone have a stopwatch function? Start it as you start recording and press "lap" at each highlight. It's quick-and-dirty, but it should work until someone suggests something more elegant. Something similar shouldn't be hard to fashion to run alongside your recording software, using the same key combination to start (but not stop) and a different global combo to mark your highlight.

Comment: If the recording software can be started/stopped in-game and does not overwrite videos, then you can stop after an interesting point and start a new video.  Then you can trim interesting parts starting from the end of your videos.  It might help if you mention what software you are using.

Comment: This isn't even really gaming related; you're just looking for a method of skimming through your own recorded videos.  This problem exists even if it's not games you're recording.

Comment: That's right, but I'm assuming that capturing real-time content with minimal interruption is something most streamers / Youtubers need to do regularly :) but anything generic will probably work for gaming too.

Answer (score 8):

If you have an nVidia GeForce GTX 650 or better graphics card, you can use their new [ShadowPlay](http://www.geforce.com/geforce-experience/shadowplay) recording software, which is currently in beta.

[image: ShadowPlay GUI]

Instead of sifting through all of your footage, you can set ShadowPlay to "shadow" you for a specific amount of time, from 1 to 20 minutes.  Just start playing, and whenever you want to, just hit the shadow record button and the last 2 (or whatever you set) minutes will be saved to disk.  There is a manual recording option to just record everything as well.

As for audio recording, you have the option to record:  "in-game audio" (which includes any other sounds, like Steam notifications, Skype call, TeamSpeak, Mumble, etc.) and/or your microphone as well.

If you use windowed or borderless windowed mode when you play games, you will need to switch to fullscreen, as ShadowPlay does not support those (yet).

[ShadowPlay example video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YX5vVs8_ROw) (pardon YouTube's compression).

Comment: My friend uses this for recording, and he loves it. It's the perfect way to capture the interesting bits without filling your hard drive with massive videos.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnJe3Y6XgRM shows how to record more than 20 minutes.